# Find records that do not have a specific value attached

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to SQL and I'm completely stuck in this query.

I have written a query for a health organization that pulls patients info, their appointment/which provider seen the patient, what location they were seen at and what documents were created during that visit and a signoff status.

When the results return, that part of the query is accurate.  (Many rows for 1 patient because of many different types of documents were generated in that one appointment)

What I am looking for, however, is to have a list of patients that have had an appointment yet  "X" document was NOT created.  I dont want to see the list of other documents created; specifically the appointments where "X" was not created. 
Please help!

This is the query that I first explained showing the patient/appointment info, and specific documents that have been generated.

```
SELECT prs.person_nbr, prs.last_name + ', '+ prs.first_name as Patient, prs.date_of_birth
  , pm.description AS Provider
  , lm.site_id
  , appts.appt_type, appts.appt_date
  , pd.document_desc, pd.signoff_status

FROM person prs 
  , patient_documents pd
  , location_mstr lm
  , provider_mstr pm
  , appointments appts

WHERE prs.person_id = appts.person_id
  and appts.enc_id = pd.enc_id
  and appts.location_id = lm.location_id
  and lm.site_id is not null
  and appts.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
  and ((pd.document_desc IN ('bms_master_im', 'Master_Im', 'BMS_ob_master','BMS_GYN_master', 'BMS_bh_master')
    and pd.signoff_status = 'P') 
    OR (pd.document_desc IN ('bms_master_im', 'Master_Im', 'BMS_ob_master',        'BMS_GYN_master', 'BMS_bh_master')
    AND pd.signoff_status IS NULL ))

ORDER BY lm.site_id, Provider
```

---

Additional info:
Tried everything suggested.
To elaborate, here's an example.

Patient: JOHN SMITH
Appointment: 20111201
Documents created: work_letter, lab_req, master_im (master_im is one of the listed to be included in the results by the IN clause)

Patient: JANE WILCOX
Appointment: 20120704
Documents created: lab_results, test_action, immunization_record.

For JOHN SMITH, the results would show that he has a master_im. Based on the already written query.

For JANE WILCOX, the results would exclude her since her documents are not listed in the IN clause.  However, I want to see her in the results so that I see that she does not have a master_im or any of the other documents listed in the IN clause created.

What i'm looking for in the end is to exclude JOHN SMITH because his appointment does have the master_im document created; and to include JANE WILCOX because she has an appointment that does not have the master_im.  (master_im can be substituted by any of the document values in the IN clause of my query)

***All patients who have an appointment that a) does not have "x" document created, or b) does have the "x" document created but the signoff status = P or NULL.  (B is easy to figure out, only need help with part a).  And we want to ignore all other documents that are not included in x.

x= 'bms_master_im', 'master_im',' bms_ob_master', 'bms_gyn_master', 'bms_bh_master', 'ob_master', 'gyn_master', 'bh_master')

Comment: do you want records where a specific type of document ( X ) is not present or records where no documents are present?

Comment: What specifiaclly is X?  Does it refer to a pd.document_desc as in your example?  Does it refer to one or many documents?

Comment: Morten, I'm looking for the records where a specific type of document (X) is not present.  Yes, X being pd.document_desc.  It refers to many documents.  For example, "master_im", "ob_master", "gyn_master", "bh_master"...and many many more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand your `WHERE` clause by adding a condition on the field that contain the "X" values you speak of. Assuming this field is located in `patient_documents.code`, your WHERE clause becomes:

```
WHERE prs.person_id = appts.person_id
and appts.enc_id = pd.enc_id
and appts.location_id = lm.location_id
and lm.site_id is not null
and appts.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id

and pd.code not in ('X', '...')

and ((pd.document_desc IN ('bms_master_im', 'Master_Im', 'BMS_ob_master','BMS_GYN_master',  'BMS_bh_master')
and pd.signoff_status = 'P') 
OR (pd.document_desc IN ('bms_master_im', 'Master_Im', 'BMS_ob_master',        'BMS_GYN_master', 'BMS_bh_master')
AND pd.signoff_status IS NULL ))
```

Note that I added the line with the whitespace on top and below. Of course, if the field containing the code is named differently, you should modify the field reference.

Comment: Hanno, tried it out and got nowhere.  1. It only allowed one value in place of X (even using () ).  2.  With only 1 value listed, it gave all of the other documents that are in the IN clause, but omitted the value I placed for X.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hoping this is what you are looking for. If not, please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

You need to use JOIN clauses on your tables, and a left join on the documents table.

For Example:

```
FROM person prs,
JOIN appointments appts ON prs.person_id = appts.person_id
JOIN location_mstr lm ON appts.location_id = lm.location_id   
JOIN provider_mstr pm ON ...
```

Then

```
LEFT JOIN patient_documents pd ON ...
```

Comment: Yes I have- doing this excluded those values and gave me all the values I dont even want to see in the report.